# Internet Explorer 11で表示したWebアプリからローカルのフォルダを開きたい

Tags: internet-explorer

Internet Explorer 11を利用しています。
ある `<a>` タグをクリックしたとき、ユーザー側PC上にあるフォルダを開きたいです。
ChromeやFirefoxではこれができないことを知っています。
Internet Explorerであればできるという情報を見つけて試しているのですが、難しいのでご教授ください。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

すでに試したこと

・ローカルにindex.html等のHTMLファイルを配置し、そのファイルを開いてタグをクリック > 開く。 
・Internet Exploreのインターネットオプションで信頼済みサイトにドメインの登録 > タグクリックしても反応なし

Answer (score 2):

セキュリティ上、禁止されています。Internet Explorerに限定するのであれば、ActiveXコントロールを作成し、当該マシン上にインストールの上、実行すれば実現できるかもしれません。ただし、そこまでしてしまうともはやHTMLとは言えないと思います。

Comment: sayuri様。まさにそのとおり、もはやセキュリテイもへったくりもないです。なんとも悲しい仕様です。

Answer (score 1):

Chrome では実験的に [Native File System API](https://web.dev/native-file-system/) が実装されています。実現したい機能次第では使えるかもしれません。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。Chromeでそのようなものがあるのですね。勉強になりました。

Answer (score 1):

最終的にActiveXで対応することとしました。
ボタンをクリックするとC:\workフォルダを開くようになっています。

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

    var path = "C:\\work";
    path.replace(/\u002f/g, '\\​');

    function openExplorer() {
        var openForlder = 'explorer.exe /n,/e,/root,' + path;
        var ActiveXobj = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        ActiveXobj.Run(openForlder);
    }
</script>
```

```html
<input type="button" value="ボタン" onclick="openExplorer();">
```

またInternet Explorer側の設定で信頼済みサイトに登録が必要。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

さらにInternet Option>信頼済みサイト>カスタムレベル>**スクリプトを実行しても…**　を有効にする。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]